# One table setting produces different background width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

I have to boxes with the same table settings.
Two issues:

(1) The width of the gray background is different.

(2) It is not possible to add a multiline equation via `\begin{align*}`. (Error:
`\begin{align}` allowed only in paragraph.)

Do I need two different `\SetTblrInner[mytblr]` and `\SetTblrInner[mytblr2]`?
Here is an example with the above error:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.0cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric,
                }
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                       angle eccentricity=1.55, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Rect/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2},
    Trap/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=#1, trapezium right angle=#2,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=white, colback=white,
        colframe=black,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,
        sidebyside, sidebyside gap=3mm,
        lower separated=false
        }

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % <--- added by @Jasper Habicht
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{             
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
    hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
    colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\small\bfseries]
               X[c, bg=gray!10]
               Q[c, wd=33mm]},
    colsep  = 3pt,
    cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{l},
    cell{odd[3]}{1} = {c=2}{c, fg=black, mode=math},
    row{1}  = {bg=gray!30, mode=text},
    row{2-Z}= {belowsep=4pt},
    row{odd[3-Z]} = {ht = 19mm}
                      }

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Title]
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Square            &   &   \\
    Area                &   &   \\
    \begin{align*}
    A&=a\cdot a\\
     & = a^{2}
    \end{align*}&=a\cdot a  a^2    &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=14mm/14mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["a"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["a"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    Circumference       &   &   \\
   u=4\cdot a           &   &   
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=14mm/14mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["a"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["a"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
    
\medskip
            \begin{mytblr}{}
    Pythagorean Theorem                    &   &   \\
    \textnormal{In any right-angled\\
     triangle it holds that}                       &   &   \\
    a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}  &   & 
            \tikz{[very thick]
\draw (-1.5,0)coordinate[](A)
    --(1.2,0)coordinate[](B)
    --(-1.5,1.2)coordinate[](C)
    --cycle;
% rechte Winkel
    \pic[draw,fill=gray!10,fill opacity=0.5,angle radius=4mm,"$\pmb{\cdot}$" opacity=1]
      {angle=B--A--C};
% Streckenbezeichnungen
\path (A) -- node [midway,below] {\scriptsize b} (B);
\path (A) -- node [midway,left] {\scriptsize a} (C);
\path (B) -- node [midway,above] {\scriptsize c} (C);}   \\
    \end{mytblr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In your code you have three errors:

- instead of `align*` you should use `aligned`
- for two line text in "Pythagorean Theorem" you should remove `\textnormal` command before curly brace (see MWE below)
- spurious math code after `align*` (remove it!)

*Off-topic*: for mark of right corner I would use:

- for labeling of shapes border you should use a way as I use at drawing of images in ma answer and you copied in "Square" part
- style for angle I would add to `tikzset` (you can change style name according to your wish)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.0cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric,
                }
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                       angle eccentricity=1.55, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Rect/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#2},
    Trap/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=#1, trapezium right angle=#2,
                        minimum width=30mm},
    ANG/.style = {draw, fill=gray!10, angle radius=4mm, 
                  angle eccentricity=#1},
        }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=white, colback=white,
        colframe=black,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,
        sidebyside, sidebyside gap=3mm,
        lower separated=false
        }

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % <--- added by @Jasper Habicht
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
    hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
    colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\small\bfseries]
               X[c, bg=gray!10]
               Q[c, wd=33mm]},
    colsep  = 3pt,
    cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{l},
    cell{odd[3]}{1} = {c=2}{c, fg=black, mode=math},
    row{1}  = {bg=gray!30, mode=text},
    row{2-Z}= {belowsep=4pt},
    row{odd[3-Z]} = {ht = 19mm}
                      }

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Title]
    \begin{mytblr}{}
    Square              &   &   \\
    Area                &   &   \\
    \begin{aligned}
    A&=a\cdot a\\
     & = a^{2}
    \end{aligned}       &   &
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=14mm/14mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["a"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["a"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    Circumference       &   &   \\
   u=4\cdot a           &   &
            \tikz{\node (a) [Rect=14mm/14mm] {};
                  \path (a.south west)  to["a"] (a.south east)
                        (a.south east)  to["a"] (a.north east);
                }   \\
    \end{mytblr}

\medskip
            \begin{mytblr}{}
    Pythagorean Theorem                     &   &   \\
    {In any right-angled\\
     triangle it holds that}                &   &   \\
    a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}  &   &
            \tikz{[very thick]
    \draw (0,0)coordinate[](A)
                -- (3,0)coordinate[](B)
                -- (0,1.5)coordinate[](C)
                -- cycle;
% rechte Winkel
    \pic[ANG=0.5, "$\pmb{\cdot}$"] {right angle=B--A--C};
% Streckenbezeichnungen
    \path   (A) edge ["$b$"] (B)
            (B) edge ["$c$"] (C)
            (C) edge ["$a$"] (A);
            }   \\
    \end{mytblr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```